# Rails observer not being triggered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to use an observer for password restoration via email. The idea is that I set an attribute to true for the `UserSession` model and the observer is supposed to pop when the value of this attribute is true and when the `save` method for a `User` is invoked.

This is the observer:

```
class UserObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
    observe :user
    def after_save(user)
        UserNotifier.deliver_forgot_password(user) if user.password_forgotten
    end
end
```

Which I added to `configuration/application.rb`:

```
config.active_record.observers = :user_observer
```

My `User` model, which changes the value of the attribute:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password_forgotten
  def forgot_password
    self.password_forgotten = true
  end
end
```

And the `UserSessionController` which invokes the `forgot_password` method from the `User` model.

```
class UserSessionController < ApplicationController
  def forgot_password
    @user.forgot_password
    @user.save
  end
end
```

However, it never reaches the `after_save` method from the observer. What is wrong?

Comment: Are you sure, your user record getting saved ?  Just for debugging, can you try `save!` ?

Comment: you are right, the method `save` was not returning `true`. The validations fail when I use `save!` (seems like all the attributes are missing). However, I don't get why this is happening, because the `@user` object is retreived with `User.find_by_email(params[:email])` and I am controlling if an user with such email is indeed found.

Comment: Humm.. Nice to hear you back.. :)

Comment: Look at the validation error and confirm which validation is not working.. and let me know...

Comment: If I use `save!` instead of `save` I get this error: `Validation failed: Email should look like an email address., Email can't be blank, Login is too short (minimum is 3 characters), Login should use only letters, numbers, spaces, and .-_@ please., Login can't be blank, Name can't be blank, Name is too short (minimum is 3 characters), Password can't be blank, Password confirmation can't be blank`

Comment: hummm... So what are you sending from API... should be valid.. It is simple naa ? :)

Comment: ok now this is weird, I am retrieving the user like this `@user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])` and `if @user` returns true. If I print the user's id I can see the number. However, the if I print the user's name it is an empty string. I am checking the user's name with the corresponding id in the database, and the name is not empty, like the rest of the attributes. It's like `@user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])`  creates an user with just the id, and the rest of the attributes are empty...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51978/discussion-between-arup-rakshit-and-dabadaba)